# Postdocs (Bioinformatics/NGS data science) from university of Toronto get Salary or stipend

Tags: postdocs, university, canada

I am bit puzzled, regarding the payment made to postdocs in Canada. I am a PhD and in my first postdoc (Europe). For my next assignment, I am in my final stages of negotiating a position of postdoc at University of Toronto. I looked over some advertisements for the position that said the salary will range from 60k to 80k.

My first question is:

1. In general the postdocs associated with UHN are awarded salary or stipend?
2. How much salary can I expect as this is my second postdoc (I need to run a family of 4, in Toronto)?

I know from my past experience that salaries can be negotiated, depending upon the need of hiring PI and your eagerness to join the team.

Could anyone provide me with inputs.

Many thank's in advance.

Comment: I guess the votes to close this question are related to your second question, which we cannot answer. We don't know your field, nor your experience that would help negotiating a salary. I think the first questions is interesting and should be kept open.

Comment: Hi, I will update my question.

Answer (score 4):

Postdocs at the University of Toronto are employees.  Postdoctoral research fellows are unionised as part of [CUPE 3902 Unit 5](https://www.cupe3902.org/unit-5/).  Although some agencies would like to treat postdocs as trainees, they are not.

The salaries at the University of Toronto for postdocs vary enormously, from less than $35k/year (in humanities) to over $70k/year (in computer science).  There is no general salary scale.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I added the missing information. My field is computational cancer biology (Bioinformatics).

Comment: @Angelo Ok!  Although I don't have statistics on the salary range per field, yours sounds like one that should have salaries to the upper part of the range, in line with the ads you saw.  You should be able to support a family of 4 on that in Toronto; I found that cost of living is smaller than in similarly sized cities (certainly compared to places like New York, San Francisco, or London) although I have no clue about costs for things like schooling.  Good luck!